# I want to join two tables and get the records which falls in 10 seconds interval

Tags: sql

Let's say table A is

```
Time1     name

10:05:01  a
10:05:02  a
10:05:07  a
10:05:11. a
```

Table B

```
Timedelta   name
10:05:10    a
10:05:30    a
```

---

Output

```
Time1.  Timedelta.  Name
10:05:01 10:05:10   a
10:05:02 10:05:10   a
10:05:07 10:05:10   a
```

I want those records which is comes in between the timedelta time and 10 seconds less than it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL, you can try this query:

```
select * from taba
inner join tabb on taba.Time1 <= tabb.Timedelta and  taba.Time1>=DATEADD(second, -10, tabb.Timedelta)
```

Comment: Will upvote in a while as this functionality is not working right now.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.